# Map layer displayed by ol.layer.Vector via geojson incomplete?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, geojson, geoserver

**What I Met:**

I am using Google Map as bottom map, and GeoServer as GIS server, providing WMS and WFS service.

The layer was shown correctly via WMS. However, when I tried displaying it by GeoJSON, it did NOT show completely. "Incomplete" meant: about half of the polygons were displayed, but the others not.

**What shoud I do?**

I am quite new in GIS. I tried the gsojson link, and found that GeoServer did returned a correct JSON string, with the size of over 200kB...

Could anyone know about what errors may I met? Or tell me how to fix it?

Thanks at advance!

**Data**

My GeoJSON data is like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection", 
"totalFeatures": 9, 
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.1", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.2", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.3", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.4", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ], 
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.5", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": []
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.6", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.7", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.8", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "Feature", 
        "id": "the_layer.9", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "geometry_name": "the_geom", 
        "properties": {
            "ID": "0", 
            "SYMBOL": "", 
            "NAME": ""
        }
    }
], 
"crs": {
    "type": "name", 
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
}
}}
```

**Other informtion**

GeoServer version: 2.12.1

OpenLayer3, v4.6.4

My WMS and WFS services are generated from an .shp file, which was provided by our client and it was confidential.

And here is my openlayers code:

```
  var drainageJson = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:the_layer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json',
    })
  });
```

According to [@Ian Turton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439194/ian-turton)'s advice, I tried using QGIS to access the WFS source, but QGIS showed: "Layer the_layer: Download of features for layer cite:the_layer failed or partially failed: Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1, column 8522. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5".

Then I raise logging level of GeoServer, I got [the log file](https://github.com/Andrew-M-C/misc_shares/blob/986c901ce4235c2663c14c7b78a9040f6edabdbe/geoserver_log.txt).

Comment: where all the polygons in the GeoJSON returned by GeoServer? You can use qgis (http://qgis.org) to test that out

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for your reply! I tried to access WFS by URL "http://127.0.0.1/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS", QGIS listed the layer names correctly. However, when I double clicked the layer "the_layer", it pop up an error msg: "Layer the_layer: Download of features for layer cite:the_layer failed or partially failed: Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1, column 8522. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5".

Comment: you need to check the GeoServer log file then - QGIS can read in the geoJson file directly if you save it from the browser

Comment: @IanTurtonIt was quite strange because I CAN display the layer (although incomplete) in my openlayers code (source sode newly attached to question), but failed in QGIS... Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: that is the partial fail - it gets some of it

Comment: @IanTurton But GeoServer log said nothing wrong... I have uploaded the log file of the WFS request [here](https://github.com/Andrew-M-C/misc_shares/blob/a2a4f2b7dfee6f90c8cd96065ca59282acdef0bb/geoserver_log.txt)

Comment: "OutputStream was successfully aborted." - implies something did, please turn up logging to geotools dev and try again

Comment: @IanTurton This is the first time I hear about GeoTools :-( . Do you have some quick guide of what should I do? Or I should read through documents of GeoTools?

Comment: it is the highest level of logging - see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

Comment: @IanTurton I see. I have updated the log file [here](https://github.com/Andrew-M-C/misc_shares/blob/986c901ce4235c2663c14c7b78a9040f6edabdbe/geoserver_log.txt). I did not quite understand what it is telling...

Comment: first please edit the question to include the link to the log, This is failing due to something interrupting the gml writer - either an illegal character or running out of temp disk space to zip the file?

Comment: @IanTurton The .shp file may contain Chinese character. If that is the problem, is it possible to fix it? (without modifying the .shp file, because the file contains information needed by my clients)

Comment: can you post the shapefile somewhere I can see so I can look at the issue on my machine?

Comment: @IanTurton Sorry, the shapefile is confidential, I am not allowed to post it to anyone outside our project team...

Comment: @IanTurton I had discovered the cause. There is a parameter "maxFeatures=50" in the request URL. Therefore GeoServer only returned 50 features (96 total)...